# Prevent HTMLPurifier convert &lang into &lang;

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm trying to purify link parameter, and it contains something like:

```
http://test.com/?id=1&lang=en
```

but when I pass this link to HTMLPurifier it returns it like:

```
http://test.com/?id=1〈=en
```

So a question: is there a way to prevent HTMLPurifier to represent &lang like entity?

Comment: Hmm, it might be worthwhile special casing entities inside links; it seems most browsers ignore non-semicolon terminated entities in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [correct format](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp) would be to replace the ampersand with the correct entity:

```
http://test.com/?id=1&amp;lang=en
```

Comment: Thanks! Though it looks ugly, that I need manually call something like str_replace to input url. Not just to allow HTMLPurifier handle it right =(

Answer (score 0):

simply replace your & with &amp ;

```
$url=http://test.com/?id=1&lang=en;
$url=str_replace('&', '&amp;', $url);
```